# WordPress ignores '%' character

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm experiencing weird WordPress behavior. There are some functions like `comments_popup_link`, which are supposed to provide different text for 0, 1 or n > 1 occurrences of some object (ie. comments). [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_popup_link) states, that in "many" version of text, one should put % (percent sign) as a placeholder for numeric value. Example says:

```
<?php
  comments_popup_link( 'No comments yet', '1 comment', '% comments', 'comments-link', 'Comments are off for this post');
?>
```

When I mistakenly replaced % with &, everything worked correctly:

```
<?php comments_popup_link('Napisz komentarz', 'Komentowany 1 raz', 'Komentowany & razy'); ?>
```

[image: Correct text]

However, when I fixed my mistake:

```
<?php comments_popup_link('Napisz komentarz', 'Komentowany 1 raz', 'Komentowany % razy'); ?>
```

WordPress suddenly started ignoring what I entered and used its own text instead:

[image: Invalid text]

Why does it happen? How can I fix it? I have exactly the same problem with other functions like one mentioned.

For the record, sample from Codex doesn't work as well.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the character with a "\%"

Comment: @andrew196 No effect. Still invalid text.

Comment: How about a "&#37;" the character code for the percent sign in double quotes. @Spook

Comment: @andrew196 This actually _displays_ a percent sign instead of count of comments.

Comment: Would that and the percent character not work together? Or have I misunderstood what you're looking for?

Comment: The correct result would be "Komentowany 3 razy". When I entered &#37;, I got "Komentowany % razy", which still isn't what I want.

Comment: try this: `<?php comments_popup_link('Napisz komentarz', 'Komentowany 1 raz', 'Komentowany %s razy'); ?>`